# mysql using variables with regex

Tags: mysql, regex, variables

how do i go about using Mysql variables inside... Mysql regex?

for example,

```
SET @my_var = (
SELECT 
year 
FROM blah
LIMIT 1);

SELECT 
foo,
bar
FROM my_table
WHERE date REGEXP @my_var%
```

also tried... `WHERE date REGEXP '@my_var%'`

what i'm trying to do is... `WHERE date REGEXP '2015%'`

Comment: show some sample data

Comment: You can use datepart function to match condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `concat`:

```
where col regexp concat(@my_var, '%')
```

But two things:

1. Your pattern looks more like a `LIKE` pattern than a `REGEXP` pattern.
2. Do not use `LIKE` or `REGEXP` for dates.  MySQL has many useful date functions.

So, I think you want:

```
where year(date) = 2015
```

or:

```
where date >= '2015-01-01' and date < '2016-01-01'
```

The last version is preferred because it can take advantage of an index, if available.

Comment: cheers Gordon, that answered it... where year(date) = @current_year

Answer (score 0):

Another way, depending on how organized you want to be...

```
    SET @var = 101;
    SET @regex = concat("^",@var,"$");

    SELECT * FROM db.table 
    WHERE col REGEXP @regex;
```